# JSON + SOAP - Is DataContract necessary?

Tags: asp.net, json, soap, datacontract

Here's my problem.
I'm using SOAP to retrieve information from a third-party web service.
Response time is too high, so I was planning on using JSON instead, at least in a couple of methods.

For this I'm using `DataContractJsonSerializer`, but I seem to be having some trouble.
For example, in SOAP there's a method called getAvailablePublic with returns an object of type `getAvailablePublicResponse`.

There's an equivalent for this method in JSON, which also returns a an object of type `getAvailablePublicResponse`.

In order to deserialize the information I needed to create a couple of data contracts, and here are my concerns:

Do I really need to create a DataContract? Why can't I use `getAvailablePublicResponse` object from asmx?

The problem is that if I create a DataContract, I need to use a different name other than getAvailablePublicResponse, as I would have two objects with the same name (the one created by me, and the one from SOAP), and this would require making several changes in my solution.

Hope this makes sense.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your client code that is making the call to the web service? I don't know what you are using now, but I'm a fan of [RestSharp](http://www.nuget.org/packages/RestSharp/) for making remote calls and serializing JSON to C# classes. Something like this:

```
    RestClient client = new RestClient("http://some.domain.com/someservice?someparam=yes");
    var results = client.Execute<MyGreatDTOClass>(new RestRequest(Method.GET));
```